# Creating worker process in Netflix conductor in c#

Tags: netflix-conductor

I am trying to create Worker in Netflix conductor. I am not able to find any code in C# except https://github.com/courosh12/conductor-dotnet-client .

Please provide link where i can refer for C#

Comment: I have found code https://github.com/erikbrgr/supersimpleconductor which helped in creating worker

Answer (score 0):

The Conductor community recently launched a SDK repository that has a user submitted C# SDK.  Perhaps that will help?
https://github.com/conductor-sdk/conductor-csharp